# Non-parse POM. POM in .m2 folder corrupted

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

Hello I am try to build `mvn package -DskipTests` a spring project and I get the following error.

Following is the error log

> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
> [FATAL] **Non-parseable POM** **/home/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen ..."** "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">... @1:127)  @ /home/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom, line 1, column 127

When I googled about this error, I read somewhere that when you run maven behind a proxy, it will not be able to access the central maven (Hence not able to download). And hence this error might occur.

I am running on **Ubuntu and system proxy is OFF**.I tried running the same on a VM, I faced the same problem.

How can I resolve this error?

Thank you!!

Comment: have you thought of uploading the file to somewhere like Google Drive and sharing a link. Looking at the corrupted file might shed some light...

Comment: Not assuming anything ... but are you running  `mvn` from the root directory?

Comment: Could you please try deleting the .m2 folder/directory itself and run the maven command again?

Comment: !Got timedout :-( ! 
I have often times run  mvn from the wrong directory by accident, I get similar error messages.

Comment: Strong recommendation. Turn on checksum policy and read https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/ first step completely remove your local cache turn on checksum and rebuild that parts you need.

Comment: @JGFMK, added the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The problem was with my dns.
The dns lookup has to do be done elsewhere instead of what verizon provides by default.

Steps:

1. Edit sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
2. Comment out last two lines, and change nameserver to 1.1.1.1

nameserver 1.1.1.1
#options *****
#search ***.***

3. Restart network using sudo netplan apply
4. Delete ./m2 folder
5. Build mvn clean package to install all the packages.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things going on here.

(Here is the link to the description page for the artifact that your Maven is trying to download: https://search.maven.org/classic/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.boot%7Cspring-boot-starter-parent%7C2.0.3.RELEASE%7Cpom).

The reason you're getting an HTML page when you ask for something that doesn't exist (you'd expect to get a 404) is thanks to Verizon jumping in and screwing everything up.  Verizon has a horrible, godawful feature enabled by default called "Search Assist".  Basically, it ensures that instead of a 404 being returned to your HTTP client (Maven in this case), a 200 response will be sent instead with some HTML in it that is designed to boost their advertising revenue.  Fortunately [you can turn it off](https://www.verizon.com/support/residential/internet/home-network/settings/opt-out-of-dns-assist).

I don't know why your Maven is not finding the release in question.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. 
1. How do I change the artifact version, cause it was not a typo, a file with a name spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom was generated.

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected: it does appear to exist in Maven Central: https://search.maven.org/classic/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.boot%7Cspring-boot-starter-parent%7C2.0.3.RELEASE%7Cpom.  I'll edit that part out of my answer.